# Change rights to a file to be readonly

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-security

How can I set a file to be readonly?

I'm using WPF with C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
 File.SetAttributes("pathToTheFile", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

More examples on msdn :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes(v=vs.110).aspx